# libGDX game resolution set to 1920x1080 need to scale down for smaller devices

Tags: java, libgdx

My games physics and collision is all at 1920x1080 and it is multiplayer. It only works on a 1080p screen; how do I scale down the game to fit on a smaller screen?

Viewport only seems to let me scale upwards but not downwards. I just want to stretch the aspect ratio.

Comment: what is your setup code to start with ? does this [config wiki page](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Fullscreen-%26-vsync) helps you ?

Comment: @dvhh basically I want to render the game at 1920 by 1080 no matter what and then stretch it to make it fit on any screen. I need to preserve each pixel for the purposes of my physics and such. It seems the Scaling.stretch viewport is what I want but I don't seem to be implementing it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To scale up or down you need to create a ViewPort like so.

```
Viewport viewport = new ScalingViewport(Scaling.stretch,width,height,camera);
```

Scaling.stretch means it will scretch the screen to fit the resolution that you put for width and height.

The key part you were forgetting is that you can't use Gdx.graphics.getHeight() anymore.

Instead you use it like so

```
camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth/2,camera.viewportHeight/2,0);
```

use camera.viewportWidth where you would usually use Gdx.graphics.getWidth() and so on. Also when you get coordinates from user input for example do not forget to use camera.unproject on a vector3 this will fix the coordinates to display on your screen.